# MySQL: does it matter to give names to the foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Tell me please either should I to give name the foreign key?

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name (columns)
REFERENCES parent_table(columns)
ON DELETE action
ON UPDATE action
```

I can do some manipulations with the constraint by it's name, but what I can do with the foreign key name? Give me some examples please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation explains:

> MySQL requires indexes on **foreign keys** and **referenced keys** so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. **In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.** Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

In other words, what you are providing is not a "foreign key name" but a "(foreign key) index name".

Having a name for an index is useful for tracking that index.

To be honest, though, I don't provide such names.  I would much rather explicitly declare an index on the foreign keys, rather than have the database do it for me.

(Note:  Most databases do not automatically create an index when a foreign key is declared.)

Comment: Thank you, that was what I need!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

If you want to alter or drop constraint in future,then it is possible using name only.

**`DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name;`**

You can  [**`check here`**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/).

Comment: But my question was: "How can I use `foreign_key_name`?", not `constarint_name`